# How to get labels and axis titles on all subplots (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

What am I doing wrong here? Tried reading through all the previous answers to the same problem but could not figure out what the problem is, why does the legend etc only go on the last subplot? Probably a really simple thing I'm missing here..

```
#Create subplot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(12,8));
axes
#parse into own variables
ax11 = axes[0][0]
ax12 = axes[0][1]
ax21 = axes[1][0]
ax22 = axes[1][1]

# Set plot line width
line_width = 1.5

# Plot data
ax11.plot(winter_temps, label='Winter')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Anomaly in temperature during winters 1953-2016')
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.ylabel('Temperature anomaly (Celsius)')

ax12.plot(spring_temps, label='Spring')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Anomaly in temperature during springs 1953-2016')
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.ylabel('Temperature anomaly (Celsius)')

ax21.plot(summer_temps, label='Summer')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Anomaly in temperature during summers 1953-2016')
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.ylabel('Temperature anomaly (Celsius)')

ax22.plot(fall_temps, label='Fall')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Anomaly in temperature during falls 1953-2016')
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.ylabel('Temperature anomaly (Celsius)')

# Set y-axis limits
ax11.set_ylim(min_temp, max_temp)
ax12.set_ylim(min_temp, max_temp)
ax21.set_ylim(min_temp, max_temp)
ax22.set_ylim(min_temp, max_temp)

# Turn plot grids on
ax11.grid()
ax12.grid()
ax21.grid()
ax22.grid()
```

Output:
[image: Output]

It all also gives me the error:

```
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
```

So the thing is I want the legend, axis titles and plot title to each subplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the per-subplot handles, you will produce the desired result of a legend in each subfigure - 
either change your calls to `plt.legend()` after the plot to

```
ax11.legend()
ax12.legend()
```

etc,

or more simply/more generally, just iterate over all of the handles at the end:

```
for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.legend(loc='best')
```

**EDIT**: a more comprehensive solution to show construction of the subplots in two parts -- things that differ vs things that are consistent.

```
# Plot data
ax11.plot(winter_temps, label='Winter')
ax11.set_title('Anomaly in temperature during winters 1953-2016')

ax12.plot(spring_temps, label='Spring')
ax12.set_title('Anomaly in temperature during springs 1953-2016')

ax21.plot(summer_temps, label='Summer')
ax21.set_title('Anomaly in temperature during summers 1953-2016')

ax22.plot(fall_temps, label='Fall')
ax22.set_title('Anomaly in temperature during falls 1953-2016')

# set up labels, limits, gridlines, legends
for ax in axes.flat:    
    ax.set_xlabel('Months')
    ax.set_ylabel('Temperature anomaly (Celsius)')
    ax.set_ylim(min_temp, max_temp)
    ax.grid('on')
    ax.legend(loc='best')
```

I would also suggest taking a look at `fig.suptitle()`, consider using a brief title per subplot ("Winter") or not at all since the legend already includes this.  And finally, check out the `sharex/sharey` arguments to `subplots(...)`; this allows you to avoid setting the dimensions independently on all four subplots and they move together if you scroll in interactive mode.

Comment: That fixes the problem with legends, but not axis-titles? if I put ax12.yabel('test') it produces error "'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'ylabel'"

Comment: sorry I overlooked that part.  I'll edit the answer with a full response, but there is a difference between the pyplot API and the axis API for some of the properties - you need to use `ax.set_<property>()` in some cases